# In Linux, how can I run a process that I can come back to later to give a command after detaching

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, fifo

I'm currently developing a server hosting app (mainly for myself / learning purposes) and everything works great and what not, I don't know how many of you are familiar with Counter-Strike in general, but I start my server and everything is ok but I detach from it (This is all written in Node.js) so I cannot use `screen` or nothing but basically if I wanted to change the level on the server, I would be able to type `changelevel de_dust2` or something if I was to launch the server manually but since I'm detached I have no way to give this process any commands.

I've read about FIFO's and using Unix sockets but all it seems to do is echo back at me, I'm not sure if I miss understand FIFO's but I thought I could

`mkfifo /tmp/server`
echo "./startserver" > /tmp/server &

and then later on if I wanted to

`echo "changelevel de_dust2" > /tmp/server`

sorry if I'm not clear, basically I have a daemon process that I want to send commands to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure your "daemon" process reads from the pipe.

```
mkfifo /tmp/server
./startserver < /tmp/server &
sleep 10000 > /tmp/server &
```

Later on, whatever you write to `/tmp/server/` appears on `startserver`'s standard input, for example:

```
echo "changelevel de_dust2" > /tmp/server
```

Note: the `sleep` command is necessary to keep the pipe open, because each `echo` command will try to close it when it ends, possibly terminating `startserver`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, `startserver` is something that is a long term process so that doesn't stop till I tell it when I type `startserver < /tmp/server` it just hangs, then I have to CTRL+C out of it and nothing ever happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Added the `sleep` command to open the pipe in the beginning. This should help. You may need to increase the delay, or replace it with `cat` to keep the pipe open forever.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! But why did it work?

Comment: When `startserver` tries to read from its STDIN, it gets blocked until someone writes to the pipe. The `sleep 10000 > /tmp/server` command doesn't write anything, but it does open the pipe for writing, which is enough to unblock the process.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways come to my mind. As long as the daemon process uses stdin/out it shouldn't be a problem to communicate with it.

1. if you use `screen`, `tmux`, or similar solution, you do not have to detach the server. You can safely keep it "attached" to the console and detach the screen itself.
2. you can use `/proc/N/fd/{0,1}` for communication as long as you have proper rights, where N is the deamon's PID, fd0 is usually the stdin and fd1 is stdout of the N process.
3. your approach with a named pipe (FIFO) is correct in essence but you're doing it only half-right. What you did was changing the stdout of the process to the pipe, meaning that all that is printed to the stdout by the daemon gets written to the pipe from where you can extract it by, say, cat. The pipe is half-duplex meaning it can only connect one input with one output. What you need are two pipes, one for input, one for output. Then whatever you send to the daemon via one pipe will get there while the response goes via the other pipe back to another program that will read the pipe.

Assume there are two pipes `pin` and `pout`. You run:

> daemon < pin >pout

Then you must run something like

> cat pout & cat > pin

in order to communicate. This is a bad example, it can have race conditions since it's asynchronous but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with Unix sockets?

Comment: Yes. But as long as you want to use simple console commands, you'd have to wrap them into some socket-aware method, such as BSD netcat (nc) and, if using Bash, you also have to keep at least one spare pipe handy since Bash, as far as my knowledge goes, can't create a socket-like two-way IPC channel. So the commands would go like this:
`daemon < pin | nc -lU socket > pin`
and the listener / command interface would look like
`nc -U socket`

Tweak the nc settings so that it stays alive after EOFs, EOLs, etc.